# Jquery AJAX appended data reset

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've this script:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#signUpForm').submit(function() {
 $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',    
 url: "process.php",
 data: $("#signUpForm").serialize(),
 success: function(data)
 {
 $('#errors').show();
 $('#errors').append(data); 
 }
 });
 return false;    
 });
  });
 </script>
```

It displays errors from php script. And right now every time I click submit button, new errors are added to old ones. I wonder, is it possible to reset old errors and show just new, after I click submit button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  `$('#errors').html(data);` instead of  `$('#errors').append(data);`, When you use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/), you add to the content you already had. [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) replaces the content.

Another alternative might be to [empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) first and then append. Like `$('#errors').empty().append(data);`

I wonder why do you have  `$('#errors').show();`? If it was hidden first, maybe better to put .show() after the .html() / .append()`

Answer (score 0):

Use $('#errors').empty().append(data);